# Does hide LOD also unload from Ram memory

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

Yesterdy i had argue with my team member about LOD (Level of Detail).[enter link description here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html). I were arguing that Hide LOD get unload from memoray as well i.e., improve performance but my team member were didn't agree with this, he said it remains in ram thus heavy the scene.

I checked official docs but it didn't mention it clearly. So what exactly LOD do? I still emphasize that it will unload the hide LOD from memory?

Answer (score 1):

Lod is a kind of feature which works with both V-Ram and system ram With V-Ram is used to render the Mesh and the system Ram is used to store the reference of the object which is unloading to load it again when the distances is proper For speed reasons the engine will need to keep all needed assets for LOD in ram at once. Mipmapping, is a (on by default) type of LOD for textures -- it's handled by the GPU and is separate from unity's LOD which is concerned with meshes.

In general meshes take up a small amount of memory.

SO conclusion is that the object is not fully unloaded until any unloading command is being run it contains the reference of mesh to make it appear quickly

A use full link against your opinion http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/lod-memory-issues-any-advice.129409/